# Lottery tickets and tax exempt organizations

Tags: taxes, tax-exemption, lottery

These might be the same scenario.

1. I am a pastor.  I find a lottery ticket in the collection plate.  The next day it wins big.  I want to cash in the ticket on behalf of the church.  My church is a tax exempt institution.  Must it pay tax on the winnings?
2. I win the powerball lottery.  I am afraid of so much money and want to donate the winning ticket to my college and wash my hands of the situation.  The college wants to claim the ticket winnings as a tax exempt organization.  Can it do this?

Comment: They are the same scenario. The answer will probably be in line with what any non-profit does to claim "income".

Comment: Tax scenarios require that you specify your location. Lottery winnings are taxed in some jurisdictions and tax-free in others.

Comment: True, this is a very similar question to the one cited by @joetaxpayer, but it had no answers.  Marking this as a duplicate question does not help anyone find an answer.

Comment: @AstPace - I see your point. The flip side, however, would be to accept many duplicate questions since 'none so far have any answers'.